Removing old logs for cloud functions
I am using this command:
gcloud logging logs delete

But it does not work as I expect.
I want to remove all the old logs for my cloud functions (myFuncOne & myFuncTwo). How should I do that ?
The documentation mentions a log name. There is no log name that I know of.
Is there a way to list the so called "log names" existing ?

Have a look at this Document1 and Document2. To know about the log name, can you check with this Link1 and link2.
